# React to a MenuButton being clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We have code that periodically refreshes our document. We also have as part of the JSF page, menuButtons (primefaces), originaly as part of dataTable cell/s in a column. We want to disable the refresh when the menuButton is clicked (the menu is expanded), and re-enable it when the menuButton is closed (to prevent page refresh from closing menu).

I've attempted to catch menuButton events using java script, but to no avail. Part of the problem is that I do not know how to identify the JSF component uniquely from javascript, as ID does not seem to work when attempting to catch events. There also does not exist any satisfactory event attributes (as part of Primefaces menuButton) that I can hook up to javascript.

Below is the minimal code that I could extract. I have extracted the menu to be on its own (not part of dataTable) for simplicity, as the question still stands. I may have a reference to a bean and dictionary files in there, but you should get the idea:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

   <h:form id="virtualMachineTableForm">

      <!-- Lazy load table -->
      <p:remoteCommand name="lazyload" 
                       update=":vmGroupTabs:virtualMachineTableForm:testMenu" 
                       actionListener="#{backupGroupController.refreshHard()}" />

      <!-- Refresh hard button -->
      <p:commandButton id="refreshButton" 
                       update=":vmGroupTabs:virtualMachineTableForm:testMenu" 
                       icon="ui-icon-refresh" 
                       immediate="true" 
                       title="#{msg.action_refresh}" 
                       actionListener="#{backupGroupController.refreshHard()}"/>

      <p:menuButton
         id="testMenu"
         value="#{msg.menuButton_SelectItem}">
         <p:menuitem
            value="Toggle refresh"
            onclick="toggleRefreshState()">
         </p:menuitem>
      </p:menuButton>

      <!-- Poller -->
      <p:poll interval="5" listener="#{backupGroupController.refreshSoft()}" 
              update=":vmGroupTabs:virtualMachineTableForm:testMenu" widgetVar="poll" />
   </h:form>

   <script type="text/javascript">

      var toggleRefreshState = function(){
         if (poll.isActive()) {
            poll.stop();
            alert("Poller stopped" );
         }
         else {
            poll.start();
            alert("Poller started" );
         }
      };

      $(document).ready(function(){
         poll.start();
         setTimeout("lazyload();", 100);
      });
//
//      $("???SomeWayToIdentifyMenu???").on({
//            onMenuOpen???: function(){
//               alert("Opening menu - stopping refresh");
//            }
//            onMenuClose???: function(){
//               alert("Closing menu - starting refresh");
//            }
//      });
</script>

</ui:composition>
```

- Is it possible to catch menu open/close (or for that matter any) events for jsf primefaces menu buttons on the client side using Java script?
- Is it possible to determine if the menubutton is open/closed for the purpose of disabling refresh to prevent menu from disappearing.

Your help appreciated, Thank you,

Werner

Comment: I have read it, and I'm not sure what you're on about.  One does not need sourcecode to answer this question.

Comment: @Kukeltje, I'm not a web developer, therefore I'm not pedantic about these things (perhaps I won't be pedantic irrespective) . I've noticed menuButton is a primefaces component (also jsf...) . I never mentioned basic jsf, but I'll add that to the question.

Comment: At least, I've only recently started with web development. You're help appreciated.

Comment: This would be easier to answer accurately with sections of your source code. Including the definition of your menuButton and how you are doing your refresh, how you are showing and hiding the menu.

Comment: @DavidWaters. I'll try and post minimal source tomorrow. My apologies for thinking that given one knows primefaces menubutton is used, the answer would be straight forward.

Comment: @Kukeltje. I've updated the post with source code. I hope this helps my case better. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it is all html, javascript and css. Javascript in PF is mainly jquery and all components have javascript code behind them to function on the client side.

There are several ways to plug into this. Attaching plain jquery event handlers to the right element (checkable via your browser developer tool and/or checking what the PrimeFaces javascript does) is an option, but you have to reapply them over and over again when e.g. ajax calls take place. Another option is to override the basic menu button functionality without changing the PF original source.

Since the code is open source, you can try to find the javascript source of the PrimeFaces MenuButton. It is in this case all defined in [menu.js](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/menu/menu.js#784) and this can be fairly easily looked at (and is cleanly written)

In there you can see all events that are added to the component and also if there e.g. are onBeforeShow handlers or not (some components in PrimeFaces have those, the MenuButton not which is unfortunate for you, but I've not seen a usecase like this up to now).

The downside of overriding the basic functionality unfortunatly is that this will then be true for *all* menu buttons. So you have to implement some logic to decide if you actually need to perform some custom action or not. There are several ways to do that, but the easiest in my opinion is to check for the presence of a specific style class (e.g. 'stopPoll').

Now to the actual overriding:

```
var oldPFShow = PrimeFaces.widget.MenuButton.prototype.show
PrimeFaces.widget.MenuButton.prototype.show = function() {
  alert("before show");
  oldPFShow.apply(this, arguments);
}

var oldPFHide = PrimeFaces.widget.MenuButton.prototype.hide
PrimeFaces.widget.MenuButton.prototype.hide = function() {
  oldPFHide.apply(this, arguments);
  alert("after hide");
}
```

(do not forget to call the original functions)

Where I put the alerts, you have to implement checking for the presence of a class or leave that out if you have one menu button on that page or want the behaviour for all menubuttons

Some general comments: (Will be removed later on, but difficult to format in the comments)

> I've attempted to catch menuButton events using java script, but to no
>   avail.

Posting attempts can help, since sometimes you are close and just have some small oversight). In those cases it is easier to write an answer for people trying to give support

> Part of the problem is that I do not know how to identify the
>   JSF component uniquely from javascript,

This is a generic PrimeFaces thing (and differs from component sets). Apply a widgetVar attribute and with PF('') you have a handle to the specific components.

And as you can see the explicit fact that you use a PrimeFaces menuButton is of the highest importance. Having a small piece of code (smaller then you have now, but compliments for the mcve) is confirmation of this (assumption is the mother of all... ) Adding 'javascript' as a very generic tag, often attracts the 'wrong' people, as does 'java' So please next time leave those out

Comment: We've changed to code as suggested by performing the override. Initially we called the override in @(document).ready, but we found that at some point in time, the client Javascript code is replaced by the original. We then hooked the call onto ajaxStatus. This too worked for a while but stopped working after a while (MenuButton javascript (all isolated to a single file) seemed to be replaced). Now to find an event in which one can reliably perform the override...

Comment: Just include it like normal javascript. No need to load it each time then. Just make sure it is loaded AFTER primefaces.js

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to add javascript to the menuButtons to change a global variable and have the periodic refresh read that global variable and act accordingly. As you have no code or indication what components you are using I can't get more specific then that. Here would be the javascript code I would expect to see

```
window.preventRefresh = false;

function doPeriodicRefresh() {
  if(!preventRefresh) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
} 

setInterval(doPeriodicRefresh, 60000);

function showMenu() {
  window.preventRefresh = true;
  menu.show();
}

function hideMenu() {
  window.preventRefresh = false;
  menu.hide();
}
```

Your mouseovers/mouseout for the menu should call showMenu and hideMenu, any parameters would have to be proxied through.

This also depends on how you are doing your periodic refresh. If you are using the `refresh` header or metatag I don't believe you will be able to stop these from javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the source with me, but I'll post some tomorrow. In my EL page I'm using the primefaces menubutton. The menubutton does not seem to have events to hook the "on" handlers, that's why I was thinking of doing it clientside.

Comment: I think this example is way to generic (plain html/javascript oriented) to be of help. The main issue by the OP is to actually hook events on the menu components

Comment: @DavidWaters, I've updated the post with source code. I hope this gives you more context.